# how to control scaling of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used the property of scaling to scale my image but its size goes on increasing and decreasing. Can't I control the scaling option? I am using this code.

```
<img src="test.gif" id="test"alt="Online Test portal" 
    style="position:absolute;top:935.5px;left:300px" 
    title="online test portal" 
    onmouseover= "new Effect.Scale('test', 150,{scaleX: true, scaleY: true}); 
    return false;" onmouseout="new Effect.Scale('test', 66.67,{scaleX: true, 
    scaleY: true}); return false;" />
```

Comment: Can you describe more specifically, what do you mean by "Can't i control the scaling option" ?  
This scriptaculous library provides some controls; http://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/effect-scale/

Comment: @SrikukanAjith: mean image resizes everytime i put my mouse over it. image always resizes to the percentage mentioned can't this happen just 1 time???? i mean to say can't it oscillate between two positions

Comment: @LokeshTiwari Do you need the image to zoom only first time and stay zoomed?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean increasing picture size (width & height) by XX% when hovering and then return back to normal size, why not using a jQuery script as mentioned in your tags ?

Something like:

**myfile.htm**

```
<div id="toto">
  <img id="myPic" src="test.gif" id="test" alt="Online Test portal" 
    style="position:absolute;top:935.5px;left:300px" 
    title="online test portal" />
</div>
```

**myscript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var picWidth = $("img#myPic").width();  /* retrieve initial width */  
  var picHeight= $("img#myPic").height(); /* retrieve initial height*/
  var picPercen= 1.40 /* if you want to add 40% in both width & height */

  /* function when hovering in */
  $("img#myPic").hover(function(){
    $(this).width(picPercent*picWidth);        
    $(this).height(picPercent*picHeight);
  /* function when hovering out */
  }, function(){
    $(this).width(picWidth);        
    $(this).height(picHeight);
  });

});
```

Or if you want animation to avoid brutal changes:

**myscript_AnimateVersion.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var picWidth = $("img#myPic").width();  /* retrieve initial width */       
  var picHeight= $("img#myPic").height(); /* retrieve initial height*/
  var picPercen= 1.40 /* if you want to add 40% in both width & height */
  var changeTime= 300 /* animation time in milliseconds */

  /* function when hovering in */
  $("img#myPic").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({width: picPercent*picWidth, height: picPercent*picHeight}, changeTime);
  /* function when hovering out */
  }, function(){
    $(this).animate({width: picWidth, height: picHeight}, changeTime);
  });

});
```

I haven't tested this code but it, at least, gives you the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to organize the code this way to have more control on the events:

**Html**

```
<img src="test.jpg" id="test" alt="Online Test portal" style="position:absolute;top:100.5px;left:300px" title="online test portal" />
```

**Js**

```
function mouseoverHandler(){
    new Effect.Scale('test',150,{scaleX: true, scaleY: true});

    // This will remove the events bindings, if this is what you needed
        this.removeEventListener('mouseover', mouseoverHandler, false);
        this.removeEventListener('mouseout', mouseoutHandler, false);
}

function mouseoutHandler(){
    new Effect.Scale('test', 66.67,{scaleX: true, scaleY: true});
}

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mouseover', mouseoverHandler, false);
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mouseout', mouseoutHandler, false);
```